# The code to navigate to a specific page when an FCM push notification is pressed is not working

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Future setupInteractedMessage() async {
FirebaseMessaging.instance..requestPermission(
badge: true,
alert: true,
sound: true,
);
String? _fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
print("TOKEN: " + _fcmToken!);
// Get any messages which caused the application to open from
// a terminated state.
RemoteMessage? initialMessage =
await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();

```
// If the message also contains a data property with a "type" of "chat",
// navigate to a chat screen
if (initialMessage != null) {
  _handleMessage(initialMessage);
}

// Also handle any interaction when the app is in the background via a
// Stream listener
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage? message) {
  print('hello');
  _handleMessage(message!);
});

FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage? message) {
  if (message != null) {
    if (message.notification != null) {
      print(message.notification!.title);
      print(message.notification!.body);
      print(message.data["screen"]);
      print(message.data["param"]);
      flutterLocalNotificationPlugin.show(
        message.notification.hashCode,
        message.notification?.title,
        message.notification?.body,
        const NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails('channelId', 'channelName', icon: "ic_notification")
        ),
      );
    }
  }
});
```

}

void _handleMessage(RemoteMessage message) {

```
final String targetPage = message.data['screen'];

if(targetPage == 'NewMessage') {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewMessage(roomId: message.data['param'])),
  );
}
```

}

I have written the code following Firebase's official documentation, but when I tap the notification, the app opens without navigating to the desired page. What could be the problem? Please help!